# Merge the Count from two table in One

Tags: sql, join, group-by

This is below data in Table2

```
ID2        |    Count2
-----------+-----------
1345653         5
534140349       5
682527813       4
687612723       3
704318001       5
```

This is my below data in Table1

```
ID1        |    Count1
-----------+-----------
1345653         4
704318001       4
```

If you see the above table this `1345653` in Table2 has `5 count` but in Table1 it has `4 count`, In the same way this ID `704318001` in Table2 has `5 count` but in Table1 it has `4 count`. So I need to show like this in the Output.

```
ID              Count2   Count1
-----------------------------------
1345653         5        4
534140349       5        0
682527813       4        0
687612723       3        0
704318001       5        4
```

Is this possible in sql? If Yes, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL 101

```
select id2, count2, coalesce(count1, 0) as count1
  from table2
  left outer join table1
    on id1=id2
```

Comment: I have created this SQL Fiddle, [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c75b/4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c75b/4). But the query is different, but when I tried pasting your query its not working..

Answer (score 1):

Here you go
Take a look at the link below
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69056/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select isnull(ID1, ID2) ID,  isnull(Table2.count2, 0) count2, isnull(Table1.count1, 0) count1
 from Table2 full outer join Table1 
 on Table2.ID2 = Table1.ID1
```

Comment: There is nothing in the question that indicates a full outer join is required.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select T1.ID,T1.Count1 As Count2,(Case When T2.ID1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE T2.Count1) 
As Count1 From 
Tabl1 AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON 
T1.ID1=T2.ID1
```

Comment: Right general idea, but the table and column names are jumbled. (the question is a bit confusing with table2 listed before table1)